# Biquad Treble Shelf filter gain being weird

Tags: filter-design, digital-filters, biquad

Trying to compute Biquad Coefficients for use in a codec chip [TLV320AIC3100](http://www.ti.com/product/TLV320AIC3100).

Bass Shelf(boost and attenuation) work as expected. Treble Shelf attenuation works as expected but Treble Shelf boost is being weird in the sense that the amplitude difference between non treble frequencies and treble frequencies is as expected (Say 10dB) but instead of the overall gain being +10dB at treble frequencies, it ends up being +3dB(ish) and non treble frequencies end up being -7dB (instead of 0dB).

Used the TI BiQuad Calculator tool and also the tool [here](http://www.earlevel.com/main/2013/10/13/biquad-calculator-v2/)

Don't know where things are going wrong. Any guidance is much appreciated. Thank you.

Used the formulas from p3 of [this PDF](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa447/slaa447.pdf)

```
// Coefficients from the Calculator  
N0  2.336268076  
N1  -2.773236549  
N2  1.01094234  
D1  -0.680740702  
D2  0.254714569

N0_Real 2.336268076  
N1_Real -1.386618274  
N2_Real 1.01094234  

Scaling Factor  2.336268076 (Max of the above 3 values)  
Range   32767 (Fixed for the Chip - 16 bits)  

Digital Coefficients    
N0  32767  
N1  -19448  
N2  14179  
D1  11153  
D2  -8346
```

Some information:

- Sampling Frequency: 44100
- Treble Shelf Center Frequency: 7kHz (to get required boost/attenuation at 10kHz)

Comment: http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt

Answer (score 1):

It's your scaling. Don't divide the coefficients by 2.336268076  (which is exactly the gain that's missing.

Instead use proper fixed point implementation techniques (scaling, shifting, "Q" notation, etc.) to deal with numbers larger than 1. Or much easier: use floating point, if you can.